# Django-pipeline is not been able to access a file. Access Denied Error

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-pipeline

I am using Django-pipeline for asset minification and compression but there seems to be an error when I try to run

`./manage collectstatic`

I get the following error..

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: Attempted access to '/home/darwesh/projects/first/api/static/js/app/check.js' denied.
```

Here is my settings.py file

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'api/static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'api/static_final/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'api/static/')


# pipeline settings 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'check': {
        'source_filenames' : (
            STATIC_PATH + 'js/app/controllers.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': STATIC_PATH + 'js/app/check.js',
    },
}
```

Here is my file structure

```
project 
|__api
   |__static
      |__js
         |__app
            |__ controllers.js
            |__ check.js  # expected output file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
STATIC_PATH +
```

from both `source_filenames` and `output_filename`

I suspect the reason you added that was due to `./manage.py collectstatic` not producing an output in your `js/app` directory (thats what caused my confusion). To fix this in settings.py set

```
PIPELINE_ENABLED = True  # pipeline > 1.3
#PIPELINE = True  # pipeline < 1.3
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static')  # this should also be set
```

run

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

you should see your generated `output_filename`

Answer (score 1):

Another reason this can happen is if you're missing a comma in the `source_filenames` tuple with one filename, which makes it a string:

With missing comma, `('js/app/controllers.js')` is a string and throws `SuspiciousFileOperation`:

```
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'check': {
        'source_filenames' : (
            'js/app/controllers.js'
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/app/check.js',
    },
}
```

Fixed:

```
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'check': {
        'source_filenames' : (
            'js/app/controllers.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/app/check.js',
    },
}
```